# How does Magento key a product group to a product in the database

Tags: mysql, magento

From a SQL Query I need to know how does magento key the related products to the actual product itself. I read a lot of useful tips on how to do with with php

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

But I need to know how to identity these groups to a id with mysql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a related product Magento uses *`catalog_product_link`* table.

In it you have *product id*, *related product* and *link type*.

To see all link types you can check the *`catalog_product_link_type`* table.

```
SELECT link.link_id, link.product_id, link.linked_product_id, link.link_type_id, type.code 
FROM catalog_product_link link 
  LEFT JOIN catalog_product_link_type type ON link.link_type_id = type.link_type_id
WHERE 
  code = 'super' -- grouped products
  AND linked_product_id IN (123456) -- child simple product(s)
;
```

More extensive information can be found with this link:
[online Database Diagram Tool dedicated to Magento eCommerce CE Edition](http://www.magereverse.com/)

Comment: This link is broken.