# Magento: Find Group Product of Simple Product

Tags: magento

I wanted the id of group product or category url of group product assigned onto the URL of cart page, so i can send customer to category page from cart page instead product detail page.

Can Any one have the solution, i want to implement with the group product, as while adding group product. the simple product is added to cart, and from cart magento returning to the product details page, but i want to send him back to the category page, where all the group products are listed.

Comment: For a solution via Mysql: [How does Magento key a product group to a product in the database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9425959/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the Solution

getParentIdsByChild() is the mothod in

Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped